# Printing Jquery Array in HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a function called

```
function diamondDetails(data) {
  var diamondVal = [];
  var diamondNos = [];
  var diamondWeight = [];
  var rate = 0;
  var str = '';
  var shape = data.acf.shape;
  var checkedVal = $('#diamond-cut:checked').val().toUpperCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.acf.gold_details.length; i++) {
    if (data.acf.diamond_global_rate[i].diamond_cut === checkedVal) {
      rate = data.acf.diamond_global_rate[i].diamond_rate;
      for (var j = 0; j < data.acf.diamond_component.length; j++) {
        diamondNos[j] = checkedVal + ' ' + shape + ' - ' + data.acf.diamond_component[j].diamond_nos + ' Nos.';
        diamondVal[j] = 'Rs. ' + (rate * data.acf.diamond_component[j].d_component_weight);
        diamondWeight[j] = data.acf.diamond_component[j].d_component_weight + ' ct';
        str += "<tr>";
        str += '<td class="td1">' + diamondNos[j] + "</td>";
        str += "<td>Rs. " + rate + "/ct </td>";
        str += "<td>" + diamondWeight[j] + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + diamondVal[j] + "</td>";
        str += "</tr>";
      }
    }
  }

  $("#diamond-comp").html(str);
}
```

and I'm calling this function in a jquery ajax get call. The data is passed to the function to show it in a table. Now this way is not acceptable because there are lots of formatting issues. With the above code, it appears like this:
[image]

I need the table elements to appear as it would if I had coded this in angular or express with handlebars

```
{{#each details}}
<tr>
<td>{{component}}</td>
<td>{{rate}} </td>
<td>{{weight}} </td>
<td>{{value}} </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

The HTML part:

```
<h3 class="subtitle">Price Breakup</h3>

<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="">
    <td class="bold-heading">Component</td>
    <td class="bold-heading">Rate</td>
    <td class="bold-heading">Weight</td>
    <td class="bold-heading">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold-heading">Gold - <span class="purity"></span>
    </td>
    <td id="gold_rate"></td>
    <td class="gold_weight"></td>
    <td id="gold_value"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold-heading" colspan="4">Diamonds</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">GH-VS Round - 36 Nos.</td>
    <td>Rs. 71,000/ct</td>
    <td>0.151 ct</td>
    <td>Rs. 10,721</td>
  </tr>
  <div id="diamond-comp">

    <!--Want it to appear like this:   <tr>
                                                <td ></td>
                                                <td>Rs. 71,000/ct</td>
                                                <td>0.151 ct</td>
                                                <td>Rs. 10,721</td>
                                            </tr> -->
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold-heading" colspan="2">Making Charges</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="making-charges"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold-heading" colspan="2">VAT</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="vat"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you looking to do this without any external frameworks? It may be worth checking out some form of templating offered by packages such as Lodash if not. Will save the coupling aspect and you can just pass your data to a function and receive the markup you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JS is mostly fine, the problem is that you're trying to put a div in the middle of the table. That's breaking your table. You need to append the rows directly to the table, not to a random div you just stuck in the middle of your table markup.

You can use the `insertAfter()` jQuery method. Remove the div and give the row before it an ID.

Here's an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9hubep1/)

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    d = data[i];
    str = "<tr><td>"+d[0]+"</td><td>"+d[1]+"</td><td>"+d[2]+"</td><td>"+d[3]+"</td></tr>";
    $(str).insertAfter("#diamond-comp");
}
```